# Where I am getting wrong?

Tags: javascript, php

ajax in view

```
$.ajax({       //Default Dose
    data    : {'cropid':cropid},
    type    : 'post',
    url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/cropConfig/getDose",
    dataType: 'json',
    success :function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Hello");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }
})
```

code in controller

```
    function getDose()  //this will bring default configured crop Dose
    {
        $user=$this->session->userdata('user');
        //$districtid=$user['district_id'];
        $cropid=$this->input->post('cropid');
        $dose=array();
        $dose=$this->cropConfig_model->getDose($cropid);
        print_r($dose);
        echo(json_encode($dose));
    }
```

Output from controller:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [dosenumber] => 1 [per] => 20 [das] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [dosenumber] => 2 [per] => 40 [das] => 30 ) [2] => Array ( [dosenumber] => 3 [per] => 40 [das] => 30 ) ) [{"dosenumber":"1","per":"20","das":"0"},{"dosenumber":"2","per":"40","das":"30"},{"dosenumber":"3","per":"40","das":"30"}]
```

code in model

```
function getDose($cropid){       //this will bring default configured crop Dose
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('cropdose');
    $this->db->where('cropid',$cropid);
    $queryCropDose = $this->db->get();
    return $queryCropDose->result_array();
}
```

I am getting data successfuly but responce in ajax is not responding giving error which i am not able solve.

[image: this is error which i am getting]

Comment: comment this line `//print_r($dose);` it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** You need to return the `response` only `json` data not other data Because you setup the `dataType:"json"` so comment this line .then ajax will `work`

```
 //print_r($dose);
```

It will work Now.

Comment: may be there your not setup the `dataType:"json"` @Talha

Comment: But whats the problem with print_r()

Comment: whatever your echoing and print_r() and any browser output all are ajax response . so you defined the `dataType:"json"` so you need to return only json data not other string or array .

Comment: but this problem is not happening with other ajax !

Comment: May there your not printing anything except json data . @Talha

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the print_r line from your controller?

```
function getDose() {
$user=$this->session->userdata('user');
//$districtid=$user['district_id'];
$cropid=$this->input->post('cropid');
$dose=array();
$dose=$this->cropConfig_model->getDose($cropid);
//print_r($dose); <--Here!!
echo(json_encode($dose));
```

}